# Configuration For: Log Into Stack Exchange => Logged Into Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, login, stack-exchange

I have an account on Stack Overflow and one on Stack Exchange. 
I use the same email and password on each. 
It's tedious logging in twice every time. 
How do I log into both at once?

Comment: do you have third party cookies disabled in your browser?

Comment: Can you list the two (exact) URLs/domains in question?

Comment: @rene: Yes, I had 3rd party cookies blocked. Seems to go now, at least on Chrome.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: I always log on to SE first at https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2fusers%2flogin-or-signup%2fdelegated%3freturnurl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fstackexchange.com%253f_%253d2066539935&cdl=1  If I'm going to coment/reply to a post on SO and not logged in there then I am automatically directed to the SO login page https://stackoverflow.com/users/login

Comment: I've described here how Global Auth works https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312956/158100

Comment: @rene: Thanks for process description - I watched it on Network. My account seems like it's coordinated now, must've been the 3rd party cookies.

Comment: Now that Firefox blocks third party cookies by default, it's back to square one. I just don't see why SO is not just a member of the SE set of forums.